# XML Parsing in Snowflake with sub nodes

Tags: xml-parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to parse below XML.

```
<row id="C2786">
  <custID>C2786</custID>
  <name>NEW Pensions Ltd </name>
  <RegName>NEW Pensions Ltd</RegName>
  <ADDress>22 Broomfield Road</ADDress>
  <ADDress m="2">Birmingham EAST</ADDress>
  <ADDress m="3">Birmingham</ADDress>
  <ADDress m="3">B1 1AY</ADDress>
  <ADDress m="3">United Kingdom</ADDress>
  <PhoneNo m="2">+44 20 6776577</PhoneNo>
  <PhoneNo m="2" s="2">+44 20 4576787</PhoneNo>
  <CustType>Corporate</CustType>
</row>
```

I need data in below format.

Output 1

| CustID | CustName | Addressline1 | Addressline2 | Addressline3 | PostCode | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C2786 | New Pensions Lts | 22 Broomfield Road | Birmingham East | Birmingham | B1 1AY | United Kingdom |

Output 2

Output 2

| CustID | CustName | Phone No1 | Phone No 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C2786 | New Pensions Ltd | +44 20 6776577 | +44 20 4576787 |

Code I am using

```
Select
     XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'custID' ):"$"::STRING AS CustID,
     XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'name' ):"$"::STRING AS CustName,
     XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'Address' ):"$"::STRING AS AddressLine1,
     XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'Address' ):"$m=2"::STRING AS AddressLine2,
     XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'Address' ):"$m=3"::STRING AS City,
     XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'Address' ):"$m-4"::STRING AS PostCode,
     XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'Address' ):"$m=5"::STRING AS Country,
  
  FROM XMLTable;

  Select
       XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'custID' ):"$"::STRING AS CustID,
       XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'name' ):"$"::STRING AS CustName,
       XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'PhoneNo' ):"$m=2"::STRING AS Landline,
       XMLGET( XMLrecord, 'PhoneNo' ):"$m=2 s=2"::STRING AS Mobile,

    FROM XMLTable;
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Hi - so what’s the issue with the code you are using?

Comment: it is not working. i am unable to get data in desired format

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
Select
     GET(XMLGET(XMLrecord, 'custID'), '$')::string  AS CustID,
     GET(XMLGET(XMLrecord, 'name'), '$')::STRING AS CustName,
     GET(XMLGET(XMLrecord, 'ADDress', 0), '$')::STRING AS AddressLine1,
     GET(XMLGET(XMLrecord, 'ADDress', 1), '$')::STRING AS AddressLine2,
     GET(XMLGET(XMLrecord, 'ADDress', 2), '$')::STRING AS City,
     GET(XMLGET(XMLrecord, 'ADDress', 3), '$')::STRING AS PostCode,
     GET(XMLGET(XMLrecord, 'ADDress', 4), '$')::STRING AS Country
  FROM XMLTable;
```

Comment: Thanks @NickW it worked really well. However is there any way for direct access like oracle instead of giving position like 0, 1, 2...? As I have one more layer under "m" and then "s" for Phone numbers?